# Openlayers tilelayer on error does not print error correctly

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I created a way to switch between 2 osm in my application by clicking on a button.

What I'm trynig to archieve here is to have error printed when the OSM layer is recreating, if customer set a bad url for his custom osm, of if any error is detected.
Here is my tile layer :

```
 const tileLayer = new TileLayer({
      title,
      zIndex,
      source: new OSMSource({ url: osmSource })
 })
```

Then here is the way I try to get the error, if any :

```
 tileLayer.on('error',
      console.info('An error occurred.....')
    )
```

The issue I am having is that the console print the message while there is no visible error in the tile layer creation : it is displayed correcty, url is good and I still have the error message

Therefore, I tried this to see what is the error, if there is any :

```
 tileLayer.on('error',
   this.errorfunction
 )

errorFunction(e){ console.log('not working : ',  e)}
```

But when I pass wrong OSM URL like 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.pn' (note that "g" is missing in PNG) it doesn't log any error

So here is my question : how can I "catch" error on tile layer creation ? Is try/catch my best option ??

Thanks in advance for anyone answering, and have a good day

Comment: An incorrect url would cause errors when the source attempts to load tiles `tileLayer.getSource().on('tileloaderror', this.errorfunction)`